# Dynamic service injection w/ tree shaking

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm trying to create an ApiService that acts as a wrapper for a series of other services within my Angular 7 application. Currently, I am injecting my services within the constructor of parent ApiService:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import { StoreInfoService } from '@services/store-info/1.0/store-info.service';
import { MenuService } from '@services/menu/1.0/menu.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(MenuService) public menu: MenuService,
    @Inject(StoreInfoService) public storeInfo: StoreInfoService,
  ) {}
}
```

This works fine, and allows me to call my API endpoints by doing this:

```
api.storeInfo.get('S9293')
```

But this does not allow me to take advantage of tree-shaking. Every service that I inject within ApiService will be included in my app, and I anticipate having a large number of services that will be wrapped within ApiService, and not every client will need to use every service.

Is there any way to wrap services within a parent wrapper service like this, while taking full advantage of tree-shaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that you can have proper tree shaking while the service is injected into the API service (but I am open to being wrong).

I did some reading and found some pretty awesome information. [Here](https://coryrylan.com/blog/tree-shakeable-providers-and-services-in-angular) is a link demonstrating how/why tree shaking works with the new providers.

It may sound a little weird, but an alternative idea you may be able to try is to use the [`file replacements`](https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-target-specific-file-replacements) with the CLI to set up the "dynamic" providers you actually provide the old way in a module, and where they are used to use the [`@Optional`](https://angular.io/api/core/Optional) decorator on the service. Here is an example with the environment ts:

```
// abstract-service.ts
@Injectable()
export abstract class AbstractService1 {
  abstract myMethod(value: number): string;
}

// service.ts
@Injectable()
export class Service1 extends AbstractService1 {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  myMethod(value: number) {
    ..// do stuff
    return '';
  }
}

// env ts
export const environment = {
  ..
  specialProviders: [
    // no provider and having the AbstractService1 optional only has a reference to the method, no meat!
    { provide: AbstractService1, useClass: Service1 }
  ],
  ..


// angular json
"fileReplacements": [
  ..
  {
    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
    "with": "src/environments/environment.<my-env>.ts"
  }
  ..
],


// shared service ts
..
constructor(
  @Optional() public Service1: AbstractService1,
  @Optional() public Service2: MyService2,
) {}
..


// module
providers: [
  ..
  ...environment.specialProviders,
  ..
],
```

(Edits)  Added demonstration of an abstract class for the "optional" service so the meat of the class is not included in the build if it's not provided. There will still be method references where the methods are used.

Comment: Ah, very nice! I didn't know about @Optional(). I had been thinking about putting the services in a config of some sort, and the environment config should work nicely. I will try this today and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. Even when using the @Optional() decorator, the source code from the optional services is still included in the main app bundle, even when they're resolved to be null within the shared service.

Comment: Do you have a PoC you could share? I'd be happy to toy with the same level of code you are!

Comment: Sure, give me a few, I'll whip something up quickly.

Comment: I've made a sample repo here: https://github.com/NMastracchio/tree-shaking-issue

I put some info in the readme that will direct you to the problem areas.

Comment: Well, after testing this for a little bit I have to update my answer. I was only able to get this working by using the abstract pattern. Please see the updated answer!

Comment: Wow, brilliant! This will work! Thank you so much for your help, you're a life saver. I've proposed an edit to the code after implementing that suggestion.

Comment: Great edit, I'm glad this is working for you, congrats!